# If i operate setState with parameter same reference object, why this re-render..?

Tags: reactjs, setstate, rerender

I know that if state is changed, this component re-render.
But when i insert same object to setState`s parameter. this component is re-rendering.
like this

```
 obj1 = {
    do: true
  };

  obj2 = {
    do: true
  };

  obj3 = this.obj1;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    //init state
    this.state = {
      do: true
    };
    this.changeProps = this.changeProps.bind(this);
  }

  changeProps = function() {
    this.setState(this.obj3);
  };
```

here link
https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-engelbart-33dl7

Can i get some advice..?
thank you.

Comment: render function being called does not necessarily mean that changes were made to the DOM. 'call' of render may or may not lead to 'commit' to the DOM.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. I am not sure I understand what your issue is, could you elaborate?

Comment: @TabishJaved thank you for your advice :) i cant understand 100% now but i`ll try to 
 understand what you said! thank you a lot again :)
@TasosK. Thank you for your welcome :) Sincerely, i worried about ask something in this SO..but thanks to like you people, i think i can ask more. Absolutely more qualified things..ㅎㅎ thanks a lot again:)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually when you do this.setState React will see the properties in this object, which React will use to perform a shallow merge, So here

```
this.setState(this.obj3);
```

is like

```
this.setState({ do: true });
```

because that's what this object holds. so these properties React will update.

And you can use this.state to change init state only inside **constructor**, you dont mutate state in React

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks to your answer, i take what should i search. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Glad it helped :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to Anyone still looking for using Objects directly in useState.
First of All please read this article [Dangers of using Objects in useState & useEffect](https://www.coletiv.com/blog/dangers-of-using-objects-in-useState-and-useEffect-ReactJS-hooks/)

example : let your initial value in useState look like this :

```js
const [person,SetPerson]=useState('{}');
```

Then use JSON.stringify() to set your state, and use JSON.parse() to get the state as object.

Explanation  :

So in the example above we stored an empty object as our initial value but it's a format of a String that means it's primitive, so whenever we change our state, it will compare the previous state with the new state as primitive not as References.

That's it hope you like the trick :D, but if if you wanna a professional one and looks complex a little bit, you can go with useReducer or Immutable.js

Answer (score -1):

Each time you open and close brackets to define an object, you are defining a different object, no matter what properties it will have.

That is why:

```
    this.obj1 = {
      do: true
    };

    this.obj2 = {
      do: true
    };

    console.log(this.obj1 === this.obj2); // false
```

Here two objects are created in memory and a reference to each of them is assigned as value respectively to this.obj1 and this.obj2.

When you do `this.obj3 = this.obj1;`, obj3's value will be a reference to an already existing object in memory. The two object will point to the same object, so that
`console.log(this.obj1 === this.obj3); //true`.

Comment: Cause my obscure question expression, i can`t get what i want in your answer.. sorry.. but thank you :)

Comment: And by the way, `this.setState` will cause a render anyway. It doesn't check whether state has changed or not. There is another method that decides whether a render should be done after an update.

Comment: @Sulthan yes roght! i did setState({}) passing empty object. Then re-render.
thank you for your comment:)

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming your question is why does react render, when the object has not necessarily changed.

When setState is called, react triggers a call to render function. This 'call' of render function may or may not lead to 'commit' to DOM.

It leads to a 'commit' to DOM, only when there is difference in the virtual DOM created by the render 'call' and the current actual DOM.

For your optimization needs: re-renders are not the problem, while re-renders with actual commits to DOM may be.

I suggest you go through this [from kent c dodds](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/fix-the-slow-render-before-you-fix-the-re-render)

Comment: That`s correct what you think!
I must search that 'commit' meaning.
thanks a lot :)